# GoogleChart Plugin view empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, plugins

I am using CakePHP 2.x, and I need to show reports via charts. I saw this plugin for CakePHP CakePHP GoogleCharts Plugin by Scott Harwell. I did everything step-by-step and somehow my views keep on appearing empty.

There were no javascript output in the DOM.

Here is my Code:

My bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('GoogleCharts');
```

My Controller:

```
$results = $this->Statistique->getIndicateursQuants( $this->request->data );
$this->set( 'results', $results );

$chart = new GoogleCharts();
$chart->type("LineChart");  
$chart->options(array('title' => "Etat statistique du nombre de flux")); 
$chart->columns(array(
       'name' => array(
           'type' => 'string',              
            'label' => 'Name'
        ),
        'nb' => array(
            'type' => 'number',
             'label' => 'nombre',
        )
 ));
 $content_chart =array();
 foreach($results as $index => $result){
    foreach($result as $cle => $value){
                    array_push($content_chart,array("name"=>$cle,"nb"=> (int)$value));
    }
 }
 foreach($content_chart as $row){
     $chart->addRow(array('name' => $row['name'], 'nb' => $row['nb']));
 }
 $this->set(compact('chart'));
```

My view:

```
<div id="chart_div">
    <?php $this->GoogleCharts->createJsChart($chart);?>
</div>
```

I have tester in the GoogleChartsHelper, the $scriptOutput is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
options_56823e100db90 = chartOptions = {
"width":400,
"height":300,
"title":"Etat statistique du nombre de flux",
"titleTextStyle":{"color":"red"}
};
js_56823e100dc16 = chartData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Name','nombre'],
['encours',852],
['refuse',11],
['valide',13],
['cloture',91],
['total',967]]);
chart_56823e100dcaf = chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart_56823e100dcaf.draw(js_56823e100dc16, options_56823e100db90);});
```

But this isn't included in the DOM when I see source.

Plugin: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b3Ng.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, Have you solved the problem? I have exactly the same problems with you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just before `$this->set(compact('chart'));` do a `var_dump($chart);` to be sure of what you are sending to the view. This will give you some information as to what the problem is.

Also two things which you didn't mention explicitly:

1 - Have you included `App::uses('GoogleCharts', 'GoogleCharts.Lib');` in your controller?

2 - Have you included public $helpers = `array('GoogleCharts.GoogleCharts');` in your controller?

These will guide us towards a final solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your ansewer.
And I'am sure that I have included "App::uses('GoogleCharts', 'GoogleCharts.Lib');" and "$helpers = array('GoogleCharts.GoogleCharts');"

Comment: object(GoogleCharts)#104 (6) { ["type":"GoogleCharts":private]=> string(9) "LineChart" ["columns":"GoogleCharts":private]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "string" ["label"]=> string(4) "Name" } ["nb"]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(6) "number" ["label"]=> string(6) "nombre" } } ["rows":"GoogleCharts":private]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "encours" [1]=> int(0) }... }

Comment: ["options":"GoogleCharts":private]=> array(4) { ["width"]=> int(400) ["height"]=> int(300) ["title"]=> string(34) "Etat statistique du nombre de flux" ["titleTextStyle"]=> array(1) { ["color"]=> string(3) "red" } } ["callbacks":"GoogleCharts":private]=> array(0) { } ["div":"GoogleCharts":private]=> string(9) "chart_div" }